# sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=8388608 in Docker image affects host settings

Tags: ubuntu, docker, sysctl

Given the following sequence of commands run on a single machine with a Docker image present:

```
HOST$ sysctl net.core.rmem_max
net.core.rmem_max = 212992

DOCKER$ sysctl net.core.rmem_max
net.core.rmem_max = 212992
DOCKER$ sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=8388608
net.core.rmem_max = 8388608
DOCKER$ sysctl net.core.rmem_max
net.core.rmem_max = 8388608

HOST$ sysctl net.core.rmem_max
net.core.rmem_max = 8388608
```

I wouldn't expect setting a value in Docker to affect the host device; is there any way to limit this effect to Docker alone?

Furthermore, in my `Dockerfile` I have:

```
RUN echo "net.core.rmem_max=26214400\nnet.core.rmem_default=26214400\n" > /etc/sysctl.d/60-cyclonedds.conf
```

But that doesn't affect the result of `DOCKER$ sysctl net.core.rmem_max`. How can I set the value in the Docker container alone?

Both the host and Docker image are running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It doesn't look like `rmem_max` is namespaced. There was [some discussion in 2017](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netdev/patch/20170726170333.24580-1-mcroce@redhat.com/) but looks like nothing became of it.

Comment: Yep, this sysctl still uses a global variable, not a namespaced one: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/2f111a6fd5b5297b4e92f53798ca086f7c7d33a4/net/core/sysctl_net_core.c#L323